# Remove notifications sound (add "silent notifications" setting on Android)

Tags: notifications, settings, google-pixel, android-11, mute

I have a Pixel 3a with Android 11 installed on it.

I have a lot of **notifications**, like *SMS, Viber, WhatsApp, Facebook*, etc... all beeping all the day. I would like to remove *just the **sound*** of all these notifications, letting them vibrate, flash... whatever other things it does...

However, the ***calls** should not be muted*, I would like to have normal sound when someone calls me (via normal call, or via WhatsApp, Messanger, Viber, etc).

I can't believe at this day is not possible a thing like this on Android 11...

The idea is not to manage all the possible applications individually, but to **mute all NON-call sounds** in general on the phone, except "long calls" (phone and messengers calls, wake-up alarms, all calls that are waiting the user to 'finish' them).

I suppose there should be a more standard solution than [this tricky one](https://nerdschalk.com/how-to-allow-call-ringtone-while-keeping-notifications-on-silent/). I think there should be a setting like `SilentNotifications` `On/Off`, if such thing is not present, it should be (Google tracker [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/177060206) created)

Comment: have you seen the options for settings - notifications (i don't use such apps do they have call function implememented as notification)?

Comment: @alecxs the idea is not to manage all the possible applications individually, but to mute NON-call sounds in general on the phone

Comment: there is something like a solution here https://nerdschalk.com/how-to-allow-call-ringtone-while-keeping-notifications-on-silent/ but is still tricky usage of "do not disturb" mode...

Comment: ok that came to my mind next - so do not disturb settings is no solution?

Comment: @alecxs, I suppose there should be a more standard solution than that tricky one. I think there should be a setting like SilentNotifications `On/Off`, if such thing is not present, it should be.